# why i cannot visit file like "xx.jsp" (/webapps/root/xx.jsp)?

Tags: tomcat

firstly,tomcat  is started successfully,i can visit the file called "index.jsp" under "Root" directory with browser ,and the browser shows tomcat homepage,but when i try to create a new file called "xx.jsp" and visit it,the browser shows "404"(when i create a file like "xx.html",the browser shows page correctly)i wanna know the reason,I'll appreciat[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIHnX.png)e a lot if someone can give me a hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to access the tomcat resource is incorrect, as mentioned in the question the JSP file exist in root folder under webapps, unless you mapped your requests to JSP in the web.xml you have to access your JSP file this way "localhost:8080/root/xx.JSP" the location where your resource exist has a huge effect to how to access it, again unless you make some sort of request to resource mapping.

I have a file under a folder called "eeee" within my webapps and this is how I access it
[image]

Spend some time reading about [servlet mapping](https://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/) and [context mapping](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) you'll be able to understand more how to access the files you previously created.

But as a brief description:

The files you created within the application will be accessible using  localhost:port/path-to-file-after-webapps-folder/filename , you can access any file you want this way (even images and text files) but as you can see this is not safe as anyone can access any file within your website without any limit, to be able to prevent such behavior redirect [all/sub] of requests received by the server to a specific java class or jsp depending on a special criteria.

For example you have the following file in the project

[image]

to be able to access this file and map all request to this file add the following to your web.xml file:

[image]

as you can see we mapped the jsp file to all requests received by your website (/*) but for example if you want to map only request coming with specific phrase replace the * with the word you want.

This is how the file is accessible after the mapping :
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply,i gained a lot from you.and i have solved this problem so far.Anyway, may you happy every day.